# Where I can find my own Google+ Play reviews and ratings?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-account, google-plus, app-ratings

I know that now Google Play reviews and ratings are connected with my Google+ account and my name. But where exactly I can find **list of my own reviews and ratings** Google Play apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately to this moment Google not provide such feature to list all our reviews and ratings from Google Play.

But there is method to search all of ours reviews by typing to google.com phrase:

```
inurl:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details +"John Doe"
```

where **John Doe** is our name we use in Google+, but of course this name should be unique.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't list all reviews though :/

Comment: It list all the reviews indexed by Google search engine. But yes, these might be not all, especially if there are many of them.